# Procedure for finding consensus on selected numbers without sharing selection

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I was wondering if there exists an algorithm, paper, etc. for the following problem:

Assume we have a public list of numbers, let's say {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Alice and Bob both pick any subset of those numbers in secret. Is there a way for Alice and Bob to exchange their selections in such a way that neither Alice nor Bob know what the other person has picked, however they still see which numbers they both picked?

For instance: Alice picks {1, 2, 5} and Bob picks {2, 3, 4}. At the end Alice and Bob should know that they have {2} in common, however without knowing the other person's selection.

I don't know where to start looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The technique to which you refer is known as [private set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_set_intersection).

These [slides](https://cyber.biu.ac.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/15.pdf) give an introduction to the problem.

This [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/299.pdf) describes one solution using fully homomorphic encryption.